# How to solve this lifetime-related error?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Say I have the following,

```rust
type EpollEventCallback<'a> = FnMut(c_int) + Send + Sync + 'a;

struct EpollFdEventHandler<'a> {
    on_readable: Option<Box<EpollEventCallback<'a>>>,
    on_writable: Option<Box<EpollEventCallback<'a>>>,
}

// Map from c_int -> EpollFdEventHandler.
type EpollEventHandlerMap<'a> = collections::HashMap<c_int, EpollFdEventHandler<'a>>;

fn add_fd_handler
        <'a, T: Fn(bool, &'a mut EpollFdEventHandler<'a>)>(
        map: &'a mut EpollEventHandlerMap<'a>,
        fd: c_int,
        adder: T)
{
    let mut hash_entry: hash_map::Entry<'a, _, _> = map.entry(fd);
    match hash_entry {
        hash_map::Entry::Occupied(ref mut occ_e) => {
            let entry: &mut EpollFdEventHandler<'a> = occ_e.get_mut();
            adder(false, entry);
        },
        hash_map::Entry::Vacant(vac_e) => {
            /*
            adder(
                true,
                vac_e.insert(EpollFdEventHandler {
                    on_readable: None,
                    on_writable: None,
                }),
            );
            */
        }
    };
}
```

`add_fd_handler` is supposed to be a helper function for adding an "FD handler"; here, it's going to get passed a closure (`adder`) that will set either `on_readable` or `on_writable`, depending on which handler is being added. `add_fd_handler`'s job is simply doing the hash table lookup, and inserting an empty entry if required. However:

```
src/event_loop.rs:85:35: 85:48 error: `(hash_entry:std::collections::hash::map::Occupied).0` does not live long enough
src/event_loop.rs:85         hash_map::Entry::Occupied(ref mut occ_e) => {
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/event_loop.rs:82:1: 101:2 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 82:0...
src/event_loop.rs:82 {
src/event_loop.rs:83     let mut hash_entry: hash_map::Entry<'a, _, _> = map.entry(fd);
src/event_loop.rs:84     match hash_entry {
src/event_loop.rs:85         hash_map::Entry::Occupied(ref mut occ_e) => {
src/event_loop.rs:86             let entry: &mut EpollFdEventHandler<'a> = occ_e.get_mut();
src/event_loop.rs:87             adder(false, entry);
                     ...
src/event_loop.rs:83:67: 101:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 83:66
src/event_loop.rs:83     let mut hash_entry: hash_map::Entry<'a, _, _> = map.entry(fd);
src/event_loop.rs:84     match hash_entry {
src/event_loop.rs:85         hash_map::Entry::Occupied(ref mut occ_e) => {
src/event_loop.rs:86             let entry: &mut EpollFdEventHandler<'a> = occ_e.get_mut();
src/event_loop.rs:87             adder(false, entry);
src/event_loop.rs:88         },
```

The error about `occ_e` only shows up if I try to use it with `adder(false, entry)`! Rust claims `occ_e` "does not live long enough", but it's only being used right there in that branch of the `match`, so how can that be?

My *best* guess presently is that the closure's second arg, as `&'a mut` is what's the issue here; my reference in `occ_e` isn't `'a`, it's something shorter (the unspecified lifetime on `hash_entry`, I think, but I don't know how to notate that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the compiler infer the proper lifetime instead:

```
fn add_fd_handler
        <T: Fn(bool, &mut EpollFdEventHandler)>(
        map: &mut EpollEventHandlerMap,
        fd: c_int,
        adder: T)
{
    let mut hash_entry = map.entry(fd);
    match hash_entry {
        hash_map::Entry::Occupied(ref mut occ_e) => {
            let entry = occ_e.get_mut();
            adder(false, entry);
        },
        hash_map::Entry::Vacant(vac_e) => {
            /*
            adder(
                true,
                vac_e.insert(EpollFdEventHandler {
                    on_readable: None,
                    on_writable: None,
                }),
            );
            */
        }
    };
}
```

The problem is that you're letting the caller determine a lifetime for the callback, but you then invoke the callback with a mutable reference to a local variable. The caller couldn't possibly know about the lifetime of that local variable, so the compiler assumes that `'a` must outlive the current function. Yet, `entry` does not outlive the function, which is why you get an error.

The declaration `T: Fn(bool, &mut EpollFdEventHandler)` is equivalent to `T: for<'a, 'b> Fn(bool, &'a mut EpollFdEventHandler<'b>)`. The `for` keyword in this context allows you to declare that `T` must implement `Fn` for any value of the specified lifetime parameters. This is only valid for lifetime parameters, because different lifetime parameters do not cause multiple versions of a function to be defined, unlike for type parameters.